# Access Denied error on web resource Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: jquery, microsoft-dynamics, webresource

I'm trying to call a web page hosted on another domain on a iFrame inside a web resource.
I'm getting the Access Denied error when the page is trying to use the jQuery code under his code.
I've been searching the web and a found some ways that didn't worked for me.

On a side note: If a run this on FireFox it works perfectly.

Thanks so much

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<STYLE type=text/css>
html, body, iframe { width: 100%; height:  5000px }
</STYLE>

<SCRIPT language=javascript type=text/javascript>
function load() {

    try {
         var userId = window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
        var codigoVendedor;
        var url;
        var filtro = "ln_name eq 'PortalConsultas'";
        var userName;

        var desde = GetDay(-2);
        var hasta = GetDay(1);
        var result = ODataSelect('ln_links', 'ln_Url', filtro, null, false, false);

        if (result != null) {
            url = result['ln_Url'];
        } else {
            document.getElementById("SinDatos").innerHTML = 'No hay definido un link con el nombre PortalConsultas';
            return;
        }

        filtro = "SystemUserId eq guid'" + userId + "'";
        result = ODataSelect('SystemUser', 'ln_codigodevendedor,FullName', filtro, null, false, false);

        codigoVendedor = result['ln_codigodevendedor'];
        userName = result['FullName'];

        if (codigoVendedor == '' || codigoVendedor == null) {
            url = url.replace('?fechaDesde={fechaDesde}&fechaHasta={fechaHasta}&EjeId={EjeId}', '');
        } else {

            url = url.replace('{EjeId}', codigoVendedor);
            url = url.replace('{fechaDesde}', desde);
            url = url.replace('{fechaHasta}', hasta);
        }

        document.getElementById("SinDatos").innerHTML = "Cargando reporte....";
        document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
    } catch (e) {

         alert(e);
    }
 }

</SCRIPT>

<META charset=utf-8></HEAD>
<BODY style="ZOOM: 1" onload=load();>
<DIV id=SinDatos>Cargando reporte....</DIV><IFRAME id=iframe src="http://calendarnew.lanacion.com.ar/Buscador_mediciones.aspx" frameBorder=0 scrolling=yes></IFRAME></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the properties window for the HTML web resource (within the form editor), is the checkbox "Restrict cross-frame scripting" checked or not checked? You will sometimes get Access Denied if the code crosses over to a different Web domain and if the setting I mentioned above is enabled.